# Не могу понять, почему не получается?

Tags: функции, button

```html
<button onclick="abbr();">Нажми меня для запуска</button>
<p id="example"></p>
<script>
  function abbr() {
    let a = 0;
    let timerId = setTimeout(Seconds, 1000, a);
  }

  function Seconds(a) {
    let t = document.getElementById("example");
    t.innerHTML = a;
    a += 1;
    if (a > 4) {
      window.close();
    }
    return a;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button onclick="abbr();">Нажми меня для запуска</button>
<p id="example"></p>
<script>
  function abbr() {
    setTimeout(Seconds, 1000, 0);
  }

  function Seconds(a) {
    let t = document.getElementById("example");
    t.innerHTML = a;
    if (a < 4) {
      setTimeout(Seconds, 1000, a + 1);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, терь буду вставлять дополнительную функцию window.close();

Comment: ты не расскажешь мне об этом чате?

Comment: ой как чудесно получилось)) ещё раз СПС пребольшое!

Comment: @Макс Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: извини меня Игорь, а т не знаешь ли можно как то улучшить предыдущую твою запись (там где setTimeout(Seconds, 1000, a + 1);)? просто ответь да либо нет?

Comment: и где эта галочка?

Comment: @Макс Улучшить нельзя.

Comment: но это круто, что ты мне подсказал про само вызывающуюся функцию, особенно про то как ты её переделал)

Comment: надо будет запомнить и использовать её) СПС тебе

Comment: я ещё добавил else window.close();

Comment: @Макс - Молодец!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```js
function abbr() {
  let a = 0;
  let timerId = setTimeout(Seconds, 1000, a);
}
function Seconds(a) {
  let t = document.getElementById("example");
  t.innerHTML = a;
  a += 1;
  if(a > 4) { window.close(); }
  return a;   
}
```

```html
<button onclick="abbr();">Нажми меня для запуска</button>
<p id="example"></p>
```

А что именно не получается?

По хорошему ваш скрипт должен быть объявлен до элемента, в котором он используется.

Поэтому приходится вызывать/описывать нужные функции после подгрузки всей страницы (onLoad)

Comment: "ваш скрипт должен быть объявлен до элемента" - ??

Comment: Он явно ожидает, что `Seconds` вызовется больше одного раза, и что `return a;` на что-то повлияет.

Comment: да, я хочу чтобы мне было видно, как "тикает" таймер хотя бы до 4 и не выходит :( клавиша <button> располагается до скрипта!

Comment: @Zhihar это в принципе весь код, тока почему-то у меня не выходит сообразить: как сделать, так чтобы шёл таймер на 4 секунды или там для этого дела нужно больше писывать в коде?

Comment: спс тебе за ответ, но мне помогли уже!